# Objects with ? in Kotlin translates to @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable in java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a library which i have written in Kotlin. This library contains an Interface which is as shown :

```
interface IApiRes {
    fun onSuccess(response: Any?)
    fun onError(apiError: ApiError)
}
```

Now One of our client is in Java and it is using this interface. Interface translates correctly in java but ? gets translated to **@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable** and not to **@android.support.annotation.Nullable**

I understand both of them offers same functionality but i still want my translated annotation to **android.support.annotation.Nullable**
Any hint on how we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.2.30 there is no possibility to control which annotation names the Kotlin compiler uses. The JetBrains annotations are part of the Kotlin standard library, and the compiler generates code which only references the standard library, not any external components.